# mono wine to build wix project

Tags: c#, ubuntu, continuous-integration, wix

I'm trying to use mono and wine on a ubuntu machine(22.04 LTS) to build my WIX installer project that will run as part of our CI\CD process.

I'm trying to build a .wixproj using MSBuild.exe. The project has a pre build event to gather the files and generate .wxs file (heat.exe)

but when it tries to run the command I receive the following error:

```
Windows Installer XML Toolset Toolset Harvester version 
Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved.

heat.exe : error HEAT0001 : GetShortPathNameW assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)

Exception Type: System.EntryPointNotFoundException

Stack Trace:
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Extensions.UtilFinalizeHarvesterMutator+NativeMethods.GetShortPathName(string,System.Text.StringBuilder,int)
  at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Extensions.UtilFinalizeHarvesterMutator+NativeMethods.GetShortPathName (System.String fullPath) [0x00010] in <8b2afc051c77416da02c7a5aa12b5d5f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Extensions.UtilFinalizeHarvesterMutator.MutateFiles () [0x000dd] in <8b2afc051c77416da02c7a5aa12b5d5f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Extensions.UtilFinalizeHarvesterMutator.Mutate (Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.Wix wix) [0x0004f] in <8b2afc051c77416da02c7a5aa12b5d5f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Mutator.Mutate (Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Serialize.Wix wix) [0x00035] in <13acedad176f4740bcdf107d029f167c>:0 
  at Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Tools.Heat.Run (System.String[] args) [0x001cc] in <05dc1d4b31e6439dabb75d17e14330a3>:0
```

The command its trying trying to run is:

```
mono /tmp/testfolder/Installers/Application/../../packages/WiX.3.11.2/tools/heat.exe dir Application/net6.0 -dr INSTALLDIR -ke -srd -cg ApplicationComponent -var var.Build -gg -out Application/Content.wxs
```

Any body know why I might be receiving the error or how to resolve it?

I'm Using WiX.3.11.2.

Thanks